# Sending Information over a network

Tags: networking, network-programming, client-server

I have computers connected in a wifi netwrok. One of them serves as a root(lets call it server), and is directly or indirectly connected to all other computers(lets call them clients). I want to send some information from root to all nodes(information is different for each node).

Is there a way to do this without running any program on the client side(similar to PING) ?

Or the only possible way is by using sockets over client and server?

Comment: If you didn't have a program running on the other computers, then how would they know what to do with the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping does not actually send any data to the client. It just roundtrips a packet.

To receive the information you need some kind of service running on the client. Sockets are needed. For minimal communication (not reliable) use UDP and for more reliable use TCP.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this without running any program on the client side(similar to PING)?
>   Yes, provided that you don't care that the clients will never do anything with the information.

Seriously, without something on the client listening for and doing something with the data you send from the server, what do you expect?

Comment: i guess i will have to run program on client side too, anyways, thanx.